# Custom Variables in Google Analytics. One works, one doesn't

Tags: google-analytics

I've been trying to implement custom variables to track one session level event, subdomains (aka, which customers are most active)...and one page level event (I think...I want to see how many customers are adopting a new feature that we've rolled out)

The following GA code is included on every page in the site. On most pages the value for 'Showcase' is simply a blank string. On the landing page for the new feature I set it to an encoded string that we use to identify customer groups.

I've been able to get the 'Subdomain' custom variable for a while now, but for the life of me, I can't seem to get the 'Showcase' custom variable to collect data...I've attached my GA code, as well as the output from the Chrome GA debugger...

Any help would be appreciated! Thx!

```
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-31929869-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'domainname.com']);
  _gaq.push(['_addIgnoredRef', 'domainname.com']);
  _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'Subdomain', 'customer_subdomain',2]); 
  _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 2, 'Showcase', 'customer_subdomain__ChadGGGG',3]);

  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);


  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
```

Here is the output from the debugger

```
_gaq.push processing "_setAccount" for args: "[UA-31929869-1]":  ga_debug.js:18
_gaq.push processing "_setDomainName" for args: "[domainname.com]":  ga_debug.js:18
_gaq.push processing "_addIgnoredRef" for args: "[domainname.com]":  ga_debug.js:18
_gaq.push processing "_setCustomVar" for args: "[1,Subdomain,customer_subdomain,2]":  ga_debug.js:18
_gaq.push processing "_setCustomVar" for args: "[2,Showcase,customer_subdomain__ChadGGGG,3]":  ga_debug.js:18
_gaq.push processing "_trackPageview" for args: "[]":  ga_debug.js:18
Track Pageview ga_debug.js:18
Tracking beacon sent!
utmwv=5.3.3d&utms=14&utmn=1052170115&utmhn=customer_subdomain.domainname.com&utme=8(Subdomain*Showcase)9(customer_subdomain*customer_subdomain__ChadGGGG)11(2)&utmcs=UTF-8&utmsr=1440x900&utmvp=1425x260&utmsc=24-bit&utmul=en-us&utmje=1&utmfl=11.3%20r300&utmdt=Ad%20Showcase%20%7C%20Impact%20Engine&utmhid=1698418735&utmr=-&utmp=%2Fspecsheets%2Fview%2F1872&utmac=UA-31929869-1&utmcc=__utma%3D161848100.1709535606.1337723076.1341352920.1341618347.44%3B%2B__utmz%3D161848100.1340241537.36.2.utmcsr%3Dpublisher.flashadstore.net%7Cutmccn%3D(referral)%7Cutmcmd%3Dreferral%7Cutmcct%3D%2Fsellsheets%3B&utmu=qRAAAC~ ga_debug.js:18
Account ID               : UA-31929869-1
Page Title               : Ad Showcase 
Host Name                : customer_subdomain.domainname.com
Page                     : /specsheets/view/1872
Referring URL            : -
Hit ID                   : 1698418735
Visitor ID               : 1709535606
Session Count            : 44
Session Time - First     : Tue May 22 2012 14:44:36 GMT-0700 (PDT)
Session Time - Last      : Tue Jul 03 2012 15:02:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)
Session Time - Current   : Fri Jul 06 2012 16:45:47 GMT-0700 (PDT)
Campaign Time            : Wed Jun 20 2012 18:18:57 GMT-0700 (PDT)
Campaign Session         : 36
Campaign Count           : 2
Campaign Source          : publisher
Custom Var 1             : label:'Subdomain' value:'customer_subdomain' scope:'2'
Custom Var 2             : label:'Showcase' value:'customer_subdomain__ChadGGGG' scope:'Page'
Language                 : en-us
Encoding                 : UTF-8
Flash Version            : 11.3 r300
Java Enabled             : true
Screen Resolution        : 1440x900
Browser Size             : 1425x260
Color Depth              : 24-bit
Ga.js Version            : 5.3.3d
Cachebuster              : 1052170115 ga_debug.js:18
_gaq.push processing "_setAccount" for args: "[UA-5137365-60]":  ga_debug.js:18
_gaq.push processing "_setDomainName" for args: "[domainname.com]":  ga_debug.js:18
_gaq.push processing "_trackPageview" for args: "[]":  ga_debug.js:18
Track Pageview ga_debug.js:18
Tracking beacon sent!
utmwv=5.3.3d&utms=15&utmn=510447593&utmhn=customer_subdomain.domainname.com&utme=8(Subdomain*Showcase)9(customer_subdomain*customer_subdomain__ChadGGGG)11(2)&utmcs=UTF-8&utmsr=1440x900&utmvp=1425x260&utmsc=24-bit&utmul=en-us&utmje=1&utmfl=11.3%20r300&utmdt=Ad%20Showcase%20%7C&utmhid=1698418735&utmr=-&utmp=%2Fspecsheets%2Fview%2F1872&utmac=UA-5137365-60&utmcc=__utma%3D161848100.1709535606.1337723076.1341352920.1341618347.44%3B%2B__utmz%3D161848100.1340241537.36.2.utmcsr%3Dpublisher.flashadstore.net%7Cutmccn%3D(referral)%7Cutmcmd%3Dreferral%7Cutmcct%3D%2Fsellsheets%3B&utmu=qRAAAC~ ga_debug.js:18
Account ID               : UA-5137365-60
Page Title               : Ad Showcase
Host Name                : customer_subdomain.domainname.com
Page                     : /specsheets/view/1872
Referring URL            : -
Hit ID                   : 1698418735
Visitor ID               : 1709535606
Session Count            : 44
Session Time - First     : Tue May 22 2012 14:44:36 GMT-0700 (PDT)
Session Time - Last      : Tue Jul 03 2012 15:02:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)
Session Time - Current   : Fri Jul 06 2012 16:45:47 GMT-0700 (PDT)
Campaign Time            : Wed Jun 20 2012 18:18:57 GMT-0700 (PDT)
Campaign Session         : 36
Campaign Count           : 2
Campaign Source          : publisher
Custom Var 1             : label:'Subdomain' value:'customer_subdomain' scope:'2'
Custom Var 2             : label:'Showcase' value:'customer_subdomain__ChadGGGG' scope:'Page'
Language                 : en-us
Encoding                 : UTF-8
Flash Version            : 11.3 r300
Java Enabled             : true
Screen Resolution        : 1440x900
Browser Size             : 1425x260
Color Depth              : 24-bit
Ga.js Version            : 5.3.3d
Cachebuster              : 510447593 ga_debug.js:18
```

Comment: To me it seems to be working. are you sure you're looking for it in the right place. Inside GA you need to click `Custom Variable (key2)` link under the graph to see it. By default the Custom Variable report will show you the variable under slot 1.

Comment: That's a great point. Unfortunately in my case, I go to 'Audience > custom > custom variables' then I click on the link 'Custom Variable (key2)' in the 'primary dimension' row, and I get 'there is no data for this view'...really weird...it feels like it should be working from the log data, but its not....hmmm...

Comment: OMFG. I'm embarrassed to even admit this, but I had inadvertently set the wrong AccountID...but just on this page...so @eduardo, you were 100% right!